# Calling "clueless" function C++ DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, dependency-walker

Most of the time, I know how to P/Invoke C++ function from C# but at this point, I only know the functions name and I don't know what it returns and what kind parameters that should be passed.

I able to find the function name via Dependency Walker
[image: functions]

As you might guess, it's something about encrypt and decrypt packet.
So, is it possible to find out the parameters and the return types? and then call it from C# ?

Comment: You'd need to reverse engineer the code. Why don't you just read the documentation.

Comment: There is no documentation, that's why I'm asking here. Is there another way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's not enough information in the question to even begin answering it. If OP knew how to reverse-engineer the DLL in question he wouldn't be asking the question like this.

Comment: Get a library with documentation. Or hire a malware author with some props.

Comment: If there's no documentation, you're probably not meant to use it. In which case you'd have to go the reverse-engineering route.

Comment: Just ask here:  http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/